# Training Commands with easyVR

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the EasyVR Arduino Shield with Uno.

What i am trying to do is train a custom phrase like a name.

I want to be able to train the phrase directly with arduino whilst it is not connected a pc.  I have noticed in the documentation there are some references to commands like it, but i'm not sure how to go around writing code for such a thing.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi a bit late but I thought it could be useful to someone, I successed to train SD  commands without pc easyvr commander with this code:

```
// ARDUINO 1.6.6
// EasyVR Shield 2.0
// EasyVR library v1.7

#include "Arduino.h"
#if !defined(SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR)
#error "Arduino version not supported. Please update your IDE to the latest version."
#endif

#define pcSerial SERIAL_PORT_MONITOR

#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
SoftwareSerial port(12, 13);

#include "EasyVR.h"
EasyVR easyvr(port);

//

char label[33];
uint8_t data;

bool train = false;
bool recog = false;

int8_t group = EasyVR::PASSWORD;
int8_t index = 0;

void setup()
{
  pcSerial.begin(9600);
  port.begin(9600);

  while (!easyvr.detect())
  {
    pcSerial.println(F("EasyVR not detected!"));
    delay(1000);
  }

  //

  easyvr.setPinOutput(EasyVR::IO1, LOW);
  pcSerial.print(F("EasyVR detected, version "));
  pcSerial.println(easyvr.getID());
  easyvr.setTimeout(5);
  //  easyvr.setLevel(EasyVR::HARD);

  //

  printCommands();
}

void printCommands()
{
  pcSerial.print(F("Password: "));
  int16_t count = easyvr.getCommandCount(group);
  pcSerial.print(count);
  pcSerial.println(F(" command(s)"));
  for (int8_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
    if (easyvr.dumpCommand(group, idx, label, data)) {
      pcSerial.print(idx);
      pcSerial.print(F(" = "));
      pcSerial.print(label);
      pcSerial.print(F(", Trained "));
      pcSerial.print(data, DEC);
      if (!easyvr.isConflict()) pcSerial.println(F(" times, OK"));
    }
  }
}

bool checkMonitorInput()
{
  if (pcSerial.available() <= 0) return false;

  int16_t rx = pcSerial.read();
  //  pcSerial.print(rx);

  if (rx == 's')
  {
    easyvr.removeCommand(group, index);
    easyvr.addCommand(group, index);
    easyvr.setCommandLabel(group, index, "cuss");

    printCommands();
  }

  if (rx == 't')
  {
    recog = false;
    pcSerial.print("say something");
    train = true;
  }

  if (rx == 'r')
  {
    train = false;
    pcSerial.print("start recognition");
    recog = true;
  }

  //

  if (rx >= 0)
  {
    easyvr.stop();
    pcSerial.flush();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void loop()
{
  checkMonitorInput();

  if (train) {
    pcSerial.println("Train a word");
    easyvr.trainCommand(group, index);
  }

  if (recog) {
    pcSerial.println("Say the word");
    easyvr.recognizeCommand(group);
  }

  //

  do {
    if (checkMonitorInput()) return;
  }
  while (!easyvr.hasFinished());

  //

  int16_t idx = easyvr.getCommand();
  if (idx >= 0) {
    if (easyvr.dumpCommand(EasyVR::PASSWORD, idx, label, data)) {
      pcSerial.print("recognized = ");
      pcSerial.println(label);
    }
    easyvr.playSound(0, EasyVR::VOL_FULL);

  } else {
    if (easyvr.isTimeout()) pcSerial.println("Timed out, try again...");
    int16_t err = easyvr.getError();
    if (err >= 0) {
      pcSerial.print("Error 0x");
      pcSerial.println(err, HEX);
    }
  }
}
```